# Installing three nginx dynamic modules when Nginx itself is installed via yum/dnf

Tags: linux, centos, fedora, webserver, nginx

We have a limitation on the server to only install Nginx via DNF. This currently (as of this date of writing) installs Nginx v1.18.0. We cannot compile our own Nginx.

I understand that with this we cannot install "static modules" because that requires the whole of Nginx to be reinstalled. But I'd like to check how we can install the [dynamic modules](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/dynamic-modules/dynamic-modules/):

1. Nginx More Headers
2. Nginx Brotli
3. Nginx Security Headers

Most lazy suggestions on blogs etc have instructions to either compile Nginx itself, or they're just plain erroneous. Welcome any pointers. I searched here and couldn't find a question about these specific modules.

Edit: just to list the nginx modules that are in fact available in my repos currently:

```
# dnf search nginx-*
Last metadata expiration check: 0:26:34 ago on Mon 04 Jan 2021 10:56:18 PM EST.
============ Name Matched: nginx-* =========
nginx-all-modules.noarch : A meta package that installs all available Nginx modules
nginx-filesystem.noarch : The basic directory layout for the Nginx server
nginx-mimetypes.noarch : MIME type mappings for nginx
nginx-mod-http-image-filter.x86_64 : Nginx HTTP image filter module
nginx-mod-http-perl.x86_64 : Nginx HTTP perl module
nginx-mod-http-xslt-filter.x86_64 : Nginx XSLT module
nginx-mod-mail.x86_64 : Nginx mail modules
nginx-mod-stream.x86_64 : Nginx stream modules
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have access to a linux machine to check right this moment, but are any of those modules available in your package repos? They will usually be named something like `nginx-thing`, so try searching for, say, `nginx-brotli`.

Comment: Thank you Karu. I've added the list available to the question (for easier to read formatting). My three desired ones are not in the usual repos.

Comment: Darn, thought this might be easy :) What Linux distro is this?

Comment: Fedora 33 or CentOS 8. We have two where we'd like to install this. I'm hoping all these RH derivatives have similar ways? DNF/YUM works in both.

Comment: One last question, did you install nginx from EPEL or the distro repos, or did you use the repos provided directly by nginx? I ask because this becomes *significantly* more complicated if you're using anything other than the official release. If you're using the OS repos, is there any reason you can't use the official ones?

Comment: I just do `dnf install nginx`. This installs 1.18.0 on Fedora and 1.14.x on CentOS.

Comment: Can you find the modules you are looking for in a COPR?  https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/fulltext/?fulltext=nginx

Comment: Thanks, interesting resource, but none of them are listed there.

Comment: @PKHunter did you ever find an answer? The "official" repos of Nginx are so useless.